# Making C++ Project with OpenCV and librealsense

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I want to start a computer vision project using an r200 and OpenCV. I'm using the legacy librealsense library and i've ran the examples on it successfully.

Unfortunately i'm new to C++ and Cmake so i'm struggling to import things appropriately.

My project structure looks like:

```
-Project

  -build
  -librealsense //this is the directory that contains the code to run the r200
  -main.cpp //my main working file
  -CMakeLists.txt  //what i'm working on
```

my CMakeLists.txt runs successfully when i execute ../ cmake from the build directory and it looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_subdirectory(librealsense)
# add the executable
add_executable(Project main.cpp librealsense/examples/example.hpp)
target_link_libraries( Project ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(Project realsense2)
```

Note that at the moment i'm just trialing code from the examples and that librealsense/examples/example.hpp is the relative path to one of the example.hpp headers used in the example that i'm copying.

The imports that i'm using in main.cpp are as follows:

```
#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>
#include "librealsense/examples/example.hpp"          
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
```

It responds with a very verbose error message that ends with the following:

```
  ...
  "_rs2_start_processing", referenced from:
      void rs2::processing_block::start<rs2::frame_queue>(rs2::frame_queue) in main.cpp.o
  "_rs2_stream_to_string", referenced from:
      texture::show(rect const&) const in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Project] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My question is how do I actually import OpenCV and the librealsense libraries!!!

Any direction to good guides for this and CMake would make me forever grateful!

Comment: As usual, when you use a library in your program, you need to **link** the program with the library. Assuming `librealsense/` directory contains sources of the library (like [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense)), you need `target_link_libraries(Project realsense2)` at the end.

Comment: Good call, that helped things a lot but still failing for the same reason (although it does make more so that's progress!) Thank you very much.

Comment: Normally, you will would put `CMakeLists.txt` in your top-level directory, then go in a sub-directory called `build` and run `cmake ..` rather than how you describe.